# Что обозначают операторы &, ^, | и ~ в Python?

Tags: python, битовые-операции, операторы

Недавно начал изучать Python и столкнулся с операторами &, ^, |, ~. В книге Byte of Python описано следующее определение:

> & - Побитовое И.
>   Побитовая операция И над
>   числами:
>   5 & 3 даёт 1.
>   | - Побитовое ИЛИ. 
>   Побитовая операция ИЛИ над
>   числами: 
>   5 | 3 даёт 7 
>   ^ - Побитовое ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО ИЛИ. 
>   Побитовая операция ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО ИЛИ: 
>   5 ^ 3 даёт 6. 
>   ~ - Побитовое НЕ.
>   Побитовая операция НЕ для
>   числа x соответствует -(x+1):
>   ~5 даёт -6.

К примеру запись

```
i = 67
print ("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format (i & 3, i ^ 5, i | 7, ~i))
```

Выводит результат

> 3, 70, 71, -68

Прошу разъяснить, что делают эти операторы.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но вы гуглить пробовали? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы представить `ПОБИТОВОЕ "И"` наглядно:

```
print('{:08b}\n{:08b}'.format(5,3))
#00000101
#00000011
```

после применения логического "И" к каждой паре бит получится:

```
#00000001 (соответствует `1` в десятичной системе).
```

---

`Побитовое "ИЛИ"` даст:

```
#00000111  (соответствует `7` в десятичной системе)
```

чтобы перевести битовое представление в десятичное, можно воспользоваться функцией `int()`:

```
print(int('00000111', base=2))
#7
```